# Cassandra Sync and Async, which one is faster to get back the result set?

Tags: java, cassandra, driver, datastax

I'm making some tests on Datastax Cassandra. The case is described as below:

- Prerequisite: 1 Cassandra Server, a table with a complex primary key (username, id), the Selection query like this: "select * from table_name where username='abc'; and the result set is the set of 16 rows.
- Case 1: execute the query on DevCenter and it takes 1676 ms to finish
- Case 2: execute synchronously the query on Java Driver by using "session.execute(statement)" and it takes 441 ms to finish
- Case 3: execute the query on Java Driver by using the asynchronous solution as introduced in https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/async/ and it takes 1121 ms to finish

Is there someone tell me circumstances where the sync/async is more faster?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the sync/async approach is less about being faster or slower, but more about the resource utilization on your client side. Async - no long blocking for long running queries. Sync - blocking, but can be fine for fast queries. Async approach might require another programming techniques to use (Futures, callbacks..), in some programming languages it is natively better supported than in others.

Answer (score 1):

There is no worth to use async approach only for one query but it will give you performance boost for big number of queries, because your code will not wait previous queries to execute next query.